# get a list of linspace from a datasheet

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have the following code in python. This produces the beautiful DataFrame:

```
df=pd.read_csv('spt.csv')

df1 = df[['TRACK_ID','POSITION_X','POSITION_Y','POSITION_T']].copy()

N = df1.groupby('TRACK_ID').size()           
max_time = (df1.groupby(['TRACK_ID'],sort=False)['POSITION_T'].size())*(0.062)
frames = max_time/N



data = pd.DataFrame({'N':N,'max_time':max_time,'frames':frames})
print(data)

               N  frames  max_time
TRACK_ID                      
0         50   0.062     3.100
1         42   0.062     2.604
2         49   0.062     3.038
3          4   0.062     0.248
4         21   0.062     1.302
5         15   0.062     0.930
6         11   0.062     0.682
7          4   0.062     0.248
8         10   0.062     0.620
9          7   0.062     0.434
```

Then I try to produce a linspace using the parameters of my dataFrame using:

```
t=data.apply(np.linspace(0,max_time,N), axis=1)
```

this produces the error:

```
"{0}".format(str(converter)))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I already change to floats and nothing change, please someone can solve the correct way to produce a list of linspace using the parameters of DataFrame?

Comment: What's your desired output with "data.apply(np.linspace(0,max_time,N), axis=1)"?

Comment: I want to produce series from 0 to max_time divided by N intervals. For the first row (TRACK_ID=0) would it be:  [0,0.062,0.124,0.186.........3.1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after? (updated based on comments to start bins from 0.062)

```
data.apply(lambda x: tuple(np.linspace(0.062,x.max_time,x.N)),axis=1)
Out[722]: 
0    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
1    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
2    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
3                         (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248)
4    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
5    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
6    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
7                         (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248)
8    (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.43...
9     (0.062, 0.124, 0.186, 0.248, 0.31, 0.372, 0.434)
dtype: object
```

Comment: almost!! each row must take the value of each rown in column N: In my data frame example N=[50,42,49.....10,7], all the series would be the same but with different lengths

Comment: Great approach! but why the values are slightly increasing at the end?

Comment: What did you mean by increasing?

Comment: It's suppose that for all rows, in the example the series will be identical. Because max_time divided by N produces the same result for all, in consequence all the series should be the same ( with these data). However are different

Comment: Ok in that case your bins should start from 0.062 instead of 0 so that all the series will have identical elements apart from having different length because that's determined by N.

Comment: That's it, Thank you very much!!

Comment: No worries. Please accept it as the answer if you find it helpful.